undefined shows up on Modal while filtering data from JS object
I am learning JavaScript. I am trying to create input fields from my JS Object by iterating over its few (03 in this case) properties:
{
  "createdBy" : "System",
  "createdDate" : "2015-12-31T05:00:00.000+00:00",
  "lastModifiedBy" : "System",
  "lastModifiedDate" : "2023-12-31T05:00:00.000+00:00",
  "id" : 21,
  "softwarename" : "KeePass",
  "softwareprovider" : "KeePass",
  "softwareprovidercontactemail" : "admin@KeePass.com",
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/softwares/21"
    },
    "appSoftware" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/softwares/21"
    }
  }
}

My Modal:
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="modalBody">
                <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

The JavaScript:
    function myEditObjIterFunction(formData) {
        let modal = bootstrap.Modal.getOrCreateInstance(document.getElementById('myModal'));
        var target = document.querySelector("#modalBody");
        var htmlFromObj = '';
        Object.entries(formData).forEach(([key, value]) => {
            if (key == 'softwarename') {
                htmlFromObj += '<label>' + key + '</label></br><input  type="text" value="'+ value +'" id="' + key + '">' + '</br>';
            } else if (key == 'softwareprovider') {
                htmlFromObj += '<label>' + key + '</label></br><input  type="text" value="'+ value +'" id="' + key + '">' + '</br>';
            } else if (key == 'softwareprovidercontactemail'){
                htmlFromObj += '<label>' + key + '</label></br><input  type="text" value="'+ value +'" id="' + key + '">' + '</br>';
            }
        });
        target.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', htmlFromObj);
        modal.show();
    }

All goes well except an additional undefined is shown at the bottom of the three fields as shown in the pic.

What am I doing wrong here? or what I am missing here?
Any pointers/help will be greatly appreciated.

Please log formData first. That will help you and us

JS Object data/formData is there on the top in this question.

I'm not able to replicate this result: https://jsfiddle.net/mgownb06/  Is there any chance it was part of the modal already, before the function was invoked?  Or perhaps the function was invoked twice with different data?  Can you provide a [mcve] as a runnable code snippet which demonstrates the problem?

Instead of looping over the object, why don't you just get the 3 properties that you want?

@David Even invoking it multiple times won't do that. There's nothing in the function that will create a label without an input after it. And the labels can only be one of the 3 strings it checks for with if.

All of your if statements do the same thing. Why not just if (key == 'softwarename' || key == 'softwareprovider' || key == 'softwareprovidercontactemail')

@David you are right. The target was initialized and invoked in the calling method block before this function was invoked. I removed that code and it works perfectly fine. Many thanks for pointing out.

Thanks @Barmar. Yours points are very well taken and applied. Many thanks to you too.

I was using the target element of the same Modal in the calling method and was doing this: target.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', myOtherCallingMethod(data, elem));  This was creating the issue as David pointed out @Barmar

What does that have to do with either of my comments?

You were telling David about invoking multiple times. My last comment was for that purpose @Barmar

Sounds like myOtherCallingMethod() sometimes returns undefined instead of HTML.
